# Need help in getting output to go from vertical to horizontal with Python

Tags: python

looked at several other questions related to the same issue but everything that was described in those other posts have not been able to solve my problem.

Basically I want to take the vertical output and display it horizontally.

after this.

```
fh = open(file)
fhread = fh.readlines()
findz = "aa"

for line in fhread:
   if line.startswith(findz):
      line_string = line.split("-", 1)
      substring = line_string[0]
      string = (substring.replace('aa', ''))
      print(string)
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But like I mentioned above every example I have looked from the internet and tried still does not help me make this go horizontal with a space.

Thanks in advance for any help as it is very much appreciated.

Comment: `print(string, end="")`

Comment: `print(" ".join( line.split("-", 1)[0].replace('aa', '') for line in fhread if line.startswith(findz) )`

Comment: I would recommend that you consider appending to an empty list and then using a join function to connect them.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs but I am still not able to get any of those lines to work.

Comment: When I try to use the 
   print(string, end="")

I get back a syntax error of
    print(string, end='')
                            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax